# Decremento en ciclo For no funciona - ActionScript 2

Tags: array

Estoy tratando de realizar una galería de imágenes con ActionScript 2. El botón de avanzar funciona perfectamente, pero el de retroceder no funciona. Este es el código del botón de retroceder:

```
on(release){
    var imgs:Array = new Array();
    imgs[1] = {img: ImgBox1};
    imgs[2] = {img: ImgBox2};
    imgs[3] = {img: ImgBox3};
    imgs[4] = {img: ImgBox4};
    imgs[5] = {img: ImgBox5};
    imgs[6] = {img: ImgBox6};
    imgs[7] = {img: ImgBox7};
    imgs[8] = {img: ImgBox8};
    imgs[9] = {img: ImgBox9};
  for(var i:Number = 9; i <= 1;i -= 1){
    if(_global.contador <= 1){
        return false;
    }
    if(_global.contador != i){
        _root.imgs[i].img._visible = false;
    }
    if(_global.contador == i){
        _root.imgs[i].img._visible = false;
        _root.imgs[i-1].img._visible = true;
        _global.contador = i-1;
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```

¿Cuál podría ser el problema?
Se supone que al oprimir el botón de avanzar, _global.contador aumenta en 1, y al momento de usar el de retroceder debería disminuir en 1 si coincide.